# Is master theorem applicable to the recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n/2)$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science

Is master theorem applicable to the recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n/2)$?

I do not think it applies because there no $n$ term and there is no $n^k$ for a $k$ which would equal $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about master theorem a minute.

The hypothesis clearly states that $T(2^n) = T(0)$.
Now if you assume htat $T$ increasing, you get
$$
T(0)\le T(n) \le T(2^n) = T(0)\implies T(n) = T(0)
$$hence $T$ is constant. So why bother with the big theorem?

---

for practice purpose:

$$
T(n)= T(n/2)
$$
is the case 1 of the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1):
$$
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)
$$
with $0 = f(n) = O(n^c)$
for any $c$, and in particular $c < \log a / \log b$. Hence the master theorem applies and 
$$
T(n) = O(n^{\log a / \log b}) = O(1)
$$as $a=1$. So the master theorem gives the right conclusion.

Comment: we are just practicing master theorem and what functions it is applciable

Comment: @MannyPwety: I edit accordingly my answer.

Comment: here is my source http://gyazo.com/b9548f57b36372df1e5715d38f578403

Comment: OK. here the relation  is true with any $k$, so the best case applies.